# creating html paragraphs using javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small game in javascript. When the user presses a button, text is returned. I am getting the feeling that there is an easier way than writing:

```
document.getElementById("logBox").innerHTML = "<p> X event is happening <p>" + document.getElementById('logBox').innerHTML;
```

So I am trying to write a function I can use like this:

```
function LOG(input){
  document.getElementById("logBox").innerHTML = "<p> input <p>" + document.getElementById('logBox').innerHTML;
}
```

But even using the special characters sign like \ I have not been able to make it work. I have been searching for a solution but cannot seem to find one. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us a jsfiddle with a demo? Where's the html for this? You might want to assign `document.getElementById("logBox")` to a variable if you're calling it more that once.

Comment: Do you have the flexibility to use jQuery?

Comment: Your code looks pretty good too me. What's the error you're getting? Or is logBox just cleared out?

Comment: A wild guess here but the LOG name is used in the Math object. Change the function name to LOGGER to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function LOG(input){
    // get the #logBox element, then keep it in a variable
    // until the end of the function
    var logBox = document.getElementById("logBox");

    // This will never work -- unless you literally want to add a paragraph
    // that says "input" each time you call this function.
    // logBox.innerHTML = "<p> input </p>" ...

    // Try this
    logBox.innerHTML = "<p>" + input + "</p>" + logBox.innerHTML;
}
```